# How to check if an object is in array and if exist to remove it otherwise to add it?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a way to check my array and add or remove objects based on name criteria.

```js
var array = [{name: "pet"}, {name: "animals"}]

var newObject =  {name: "pet"}

var updatedArray = array.filter(el => el.name !== newObject.name)

console.log(updatedArray)
```

I am expecting to remove the object and my updatedArray to look like `[{name: "animals"}]`

Comment: Do you have a question? It looks like you already did what you wanted to do...

Comment: @Paulpro thats the problem... for me it seems fine but the result is not

Comment: it looks like you already know what to do

Comment: What does *but the result is not* mean?

Comment: I have created a snippet. The output is correct. Please check it

Comment: The result is fine. The code does exactly what you said you want it to do.

Comment: @Liam it means that it keeps adding the element and duplicate it

Comment: @MarkusHayner Please edit the snippet above to show the problem.

Comment: @MaheerAli - There's the whole "and if not add it" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing code will just remove it if it's there. It doesn't try to remember whether it was found and add it if it isn't.

To do that, I'd use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```
function removeOrAdd(array, obj) {
    var index = array.findIndex(el => el.name === newObject.name)
    if (index === -1) {
        // Not found, add it
        array.push(newObject);
    } else {
        // Found, remove it
        array.splice(index, 1);
        // or create a new array instead of splicing:
        //array = array.filter(function(_, i) { return i !== index);
    }
}
```

`findIndex` calls a callback for each array entry until the callback returns a truthy value, then stops and returns that index; if the callback never returns a truthy value, `findIndex` reutrns -1 when it runs out of entries.

Live Copy:

```js
function removeOrAdd(array, obj) {
    var index = array.findIndex(el => el.name === newObject.name)
    if (index === -1) {
        // Not found, add it
        array.push(newObject);
    } else {
        // Found, remove it
        array.splice(index, 1);
        // or create a new array instead of splicing:
        //array = array.filter(function(_, i) { return i !== index);
    }
}

var array = [{name: "pet"}, {name: "animals"}]
var newObject =  {name: "pet"}

console.log("before", array);
removeOrAdd(array, newObject); // Found, so it was removed
console.log("after1", array);
removeOrAdd(array, newObject); // Not found, so it was added
console.log("after2", array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: @Liam `some()` can't work here because the code uses the found index to remove the element i.e `array.splice(index, 1);`

Comment: You only remove one copy, instead of all matching objects.

Comment: @Liam Array#some is older than Array#findIndex

Comment: @Paulpro - That was how I read the question. Always possible I'm reading it wrong, but I don't think so.

Comment: Fair enough; OP didn't really specify. I just thought his attempt with Array#filter was because he wanted to remove every match. As long as objects are only added with addOrRemove I suppose there can never be duplicates anyway.